# The pain with the pane in JavaFX. How can you scale Nodes with fixed Top-Left Corner?

Tags: javafx, transform, scale

It seems to be a simple problem. But I found no simple solution. If you scale Nodes, the new form will be in the center of the parent. But I would like that the new form has the same Top-Left Corner as the old one.

The expample code is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestScale extends Application{
    Group root;
    Pane pane;
    Scene scene;    
    Rectangle rect0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new Group();
        scene = new Scene(root, 200, 160);
        rect0=new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 160);
        rect0.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        pane = new Pane();           
        pane.getChildren().add(rect0);
        Button btnForward = new Button();
        btnForward.setText(">");
        btnForward.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                transform(pane);
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        root.getChildren().add(btnForward);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }



    void transform (Node node){
        node.setScaleX(0.5);
        node.setScaleY(0.5);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

All tests with Stackpane, Borderpane, Anchorpane, Groups delivers no easy solution. The only way seems to be with setTransformX and setTransformY. But I need for this a complex calculation of the arguments.

Comment: `root` is a Group, which does not impose or support alignment of children. Is there any reason you can't use a `VBox` or `Hbox`? They do support alignment via `setAlignment(Pos)` and so can keep the scaled children in a fixed position relative to their upper left corner, which sounds like the effect you are after.

Answer (score 3):

When you use ScaleX/ScaleY, scaling occurs from the center of the node.

**From JavaDocs**

> The pivot point about which the scale occurs is the center of the untransformed layoutBounds.

So, if you want to translate the scaling co-ordinates, you need to take the scaling compression into account when you set the required translation values.

As your current pivot is center, you need to set Translate to a **negative value**. Since the compression of X and Y is half, so you need to translate to 1/4 of total size of the scene.

```
node.setScaleX(0.5);
node.setScaleY(0.5);
node.setTranslateX(0 - node.getScene().getWidth()/4);     
node.setTranslateY(0 - node.getScene().getHeight()/4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ist the code to transform an rectangle within an image:
The procedure deliver a scalefaktor for setScaleX and setScaleY (scale) and set value tx for setTransformX and ty for setTransformY.

```
public Scaler(double sceneWidth, double sceneHeight, double imgWidth, double imgHeight, 
            int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        double scrnRatio = sceneHeight / sceneWidth;
        double offsetX = 0.;
        double offsetY = 0.;        
        if (height / (double)width > scrnRatio) {
            offsetX = (height / scrnRatio - width) / 2.;            
            scale = sceneHeight/height;            
        } else {
            offsetY = (width * scrnRatio - height) / 2.;             
            scale = sceneWidth/width;
        }        
        double dh = (1. - scale) / 2.;
        tx = -(x - offsetX) * scale - dh * imgWidth;
        ty = -(y - offsetY) * scale - dh * imgHeight;
    }
```

There is no way for an easier code?